# How do I define the tan of this angle in terms of x and y

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I was solving a problem for a project of mine, and got stuck at this one place. Here is a link to a diagram of the problem: [image: Ellipse] From this diagram, one can say that $\tan\theta=\frac {-y}{x}$ and $\tan\omega=\frac{y-y_2}{x_2-x}$ (By dropping a perpendicular from O to the x-axis). However, I am not able to figure out a way to define $\tan\phi$ in terms of $x, y, x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2$. Any inputs are appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035764/alhazens-billiard-problem-in-an-ellipse . If you have new info regarding your original question, please update that question instead of starting new posts.

Comment: Is there a relation between A,O and B ? A and B looks two random points to me.

Comment: No they're all completely random points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angle $\phi$ is equal to:

$$\phi=\theta-\beta \implies \tan\phi=\tan(\theta-\beta)\implies \tan\phi=\frac{\tan\theta-\tan\beta}{1+\tan\theta\tan\beta}$$
The distances using points, $x,y,x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$:
$$l_1^2=(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2$$
$$l_2^2=(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2$$
$$l_3^2=(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2$$
Using the cosine rule:
$$l_1^2+l_2^2-2l_1l_2\cos\beta=l_3^2$$
We get for $\beta$: 
$$\beta=\frac{1}{2}cos^{-1}\left(\frac{l_1^2+l_2^2-l_3^2}{2l_1l_2}\right)$$
Note that:
$$\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}k\right)=\frac{\sin k}{\cos k+1}$$
$$sin\left(cos^{-1}\frac{k_1}{k_2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{k_2^2-k_1^2}}{k_2}$$
Using this to calculate $\tan\beta$:
$$\tan\beta=\frac{sin\left(cos^{-1}(\frac{l_1^2+l_2^2-l_3^2}{2l_1l_2})\right)}{cos\left(cos^{-1}(\frac{l_1^2+l_2^2-l_3^2}{2l_1l_2})\right)+1} \implies \frac{\frac{\sqrt{(2l_1l_2)^2-(l_1^2+l_2^2-l_3^2)^2}}{2l_1l_2}}{\frac{l_1^2+l_2^2-l_3^2}{2l_1l_2}+\frac{2l_1l_2}{2l_1l_2}}=\frac{\sqrt{(2l_1l_2)^2-(l_1^2+l_2^2-l_3^2)^2}}{l_1^2+l_2^2-l_3^2+2l_1l_2}$$
$$\implies\tan\beta=\frac{\sqrt{2l_1l_2-(l_1^2+l_2^2-l_3^2)}}{\sqrt{2l_1l_2+(l_1^2+l_2^2-l_3^2)}}=\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{U}}{\sqrt{V}}}$$
Substituting the last equation:
$$\tan\phi=\frac{\frac{-y}{x}-\frac{\sqrt{U}}{\sqrt{V}}}{1-\frac{y}{x}\frac{\sqrt{U}}{\sqrt{V}}}=\frac{\frac{-y\sqrt{V}}{x\sqrt{V}}-\frac{x\sqrt{U}}{x\sqrt{V}}}{\frac{x\sqrt{V}}{x\sqrt{V}}-\frac{y\sqrt{U}}{x\sqrt{V}}}=\frac{-y\sqrt{V}-x\sqrt{U}}{x\sqrt{V}-y\sqrt{U}}$$

For an ellipse with $a$ and $b$:

[image]

In this example $a=5$ and $b=4$. The product of a line and their perpendicular line must be equal to $-1$ ([SEE LINK](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-parallel-perpendicular.html)). Therefore: $$\tan\alpha=-\frac{1}{y'}$$Here $y'$ is equal to the slope of the line tangent to the ellipse. 
Calculating the slope, using the general formula of the ellipse:
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
$$\implies 2\frac{x}{a^2}+2\frac{yy'}{b^2}=0\implies y'=-\frac{b^2x}{a^2y}$$
Therefore $\tan\phi$ is equal to:
$$\tan\phi=-\tan\alpha=\frac{1}{y'}=\frac{1}{-\frac{b^2x}{a^2y}}=-\frac{a^2y}{b^2x}$$
If $a=b$, which is the case for a circle, then $\tan\phi=-\frac{y}{x}$

Comment: The thing is, the line that extends from 'A' has to be the normal, and the angles made by the lines CA and BA have to be equal as it is a reflection. This method would work if the shape was a circle, because all radii are perpendicular to the tangents, thus already forming a normal line. I tried this method, and it took a lot of time while yielding the wrong results.

Comment: You are right, so I've edited my post. Hope it helps !

Comment: $\phi = \theta - \alpha$, not $\theta - \beta$.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair According to the image $\alpha=\beta$.

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice the side annotations.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair I think there should be a solution for this problem using the foci of the ellipse, but I need to think about it. The questioner wants to use this angle, $\phi$ to solve Alhazen's billiard problem for ellipses (see comments above).

Comment: @Paulo Hey I'm a bit confused with the last step, that simplifies $\frac{-y\sqrt{V}-x\sqrt{U}}{x\sqrt{V}-y\sqrt{U}}$ to $-\frac{a^2y}{b^2x}$. Also, when you say 'For an ellipse with $a$ and $b$,' do you mean the semi minor and major axes, or is it something else?

Comment: I calculated the last step $-\frac{a^2y}{b^2x}$ using another method. In the question, you wanted a expression for $\phi$, using the coordinates of the points $A$,$B$ and $O$, but if you want to solve the Alhazen's billiard problem for ellipses, then it's better to use the last answer $-\frac{a^2y}{b^2x}$. $a$ is in this case the axis parallel to the $x$-axis and $b$ is the axis parallel to the $y$-axis

Comment: @Paulo I apologise but I still don't understand what a and b would be in numerical values for the ellipse. Also may I know this other method? Is there any form of communication which would allow you to explain this in a bit more detail?

Comment: @Paulo Also, how did you get an expression for $\tan\beta$ from the expression $\beta=\frac{1}{2}cos^{-1}\left(\frac{l_1^2+l_2^2-l_3^2}{2l_1l_2}\right)$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dhruv Bansal I used trigonometry to calculate $\tan\beta$ (which got a little bit messy), but I think you can use the last equation, which is more simple.